# Как сделать чтобы горел раздел меню на котором сейчас находится пользователь?

Tags: html, css

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light shadow-sm bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
  <span class="ml-3 ">RTR</span>
  </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar4">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
  </button>
  
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar4">
  <!-- <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto pl-lg-4"> -->
   <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" id="button" href="/dashboard/news/" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">Новости</a> 
   <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="/dashboard/sell/" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">Продажа</a>
   <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="/dashboard/buy/" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">Покупка</a> 
   <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="/dashboard/deposits/" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">Пополнение</a>
   <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="/dashboard/wallets/" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">Кошельки</a>
   <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="/dashboard/statistics/" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">Статистика</a>
   <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="/dashboard/settings/" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">Настройки</a>
   <a class="nav-link px-lg-4" href="/dashboard/faq/" style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; ">FAQ</a>

  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Обычно при помощи java script всем пунктам меню убирают, а текущему пункту добавляют класс (например active). А уже в css данному классу оформляют подсветку. Полужирность, может быть тени и другой цвет.

Comment: Не понятно, что значит "на котором сейчас находится"? Пункт меню, соответствующий открытой странице сайта? Или пункт меню, на который наведен курсор мыши?

В первом случае можно не делать пункт ссылкой на раздел — пользователь ведь уже в нем находится. А во втором — использовать селектор  a.nav-link:hover, чтобы придать доп. стиль

Comment: Если вы хотите чтобы текущий пункт меню определялся не на сервере, а на стороне пользователя, то вот здесь есть примеры кода на jQuery и простом Java Script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url